# Dictionary Formatting and defaultdict function

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping, defaultdict

I have a dictionary which is the format of `{(a,b):c, (a2,b2):c2 and so on}`. From this format, there are more than one key of `a2`, `a` and so on and for each `a`, `a2` the `b`, `b2` however occurs only once and the value `c`,`c2` for each item varies. What i need is to make a dictionary of dictionary values and single integer keys in this format: `{a:{b:c,b2:c2}}` assuming that before, `a` and `a2` are the same value.

Cheers guys (use `defaultdict` if possible). in PYTHON.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. Do you want the dict to look like `{a:{b:c}, a2:{b2:c2}}` ?

Comment: So `a` and `a2` are the same, but `b` and `b2` aren't? To get good answers, you might want to work on the clarity of your question.

Comment: Can you please give an example input and output?

Comment: you should add the expected input and output to make your question more clear.

Comment: I find it hard to say for sure what you need. Is it a homework? What is the example input data? What is the expected output for this example input data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if D is the input dict, then

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(dict)
for (a,b),c in D.items():
    res[a][b] = c
```